# regex to only show items that start with words in full capitals

Tags: regex, capitalization

I am looking for a regex string (to use in GA) that identifys entries that start with words in full capitals.

For example to include:

- IBUPROFEN : British National Formulary
- CETIRIZINE HYDROCHLORIDE : British National Formulary

but exclude:

- Antimuscarinics : British National Formulary

I have tried to use:
^[A-Z]{5,25}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To match a string that starts with an upper-case word, use:

```
^[A-Z]+\b.*
```

If you want to exclude particular upper-case words at the start of the string, for instance `TOM` and `JERRY`, modify it to:

```
^(?!(?:TOM|JERRY)\b)[A-Z]+\b.*
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[A-Z]+` matches upper-case letters
- `\b` is a word boundary that matches a position where one side is a letter, and the other side is not a letter (for instance a space character, or the beginning of the string)
- `.*` matches any chars to the end of the string

For the second one, `(?!(?:TOM|JERRY)\b)` is a negative lookahead that asserts that what follows is not `TOM` or `JERRY`, followed by a boundary.

Comment: thanks zx81. ^[A-Z]+\b.* however works for both what i need to include and what i dont (ie they both start with capitals. I just want to includes those with a string of capitals at the start. Cheers

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. `I just want to includes those with a string of capitals at the start.` Yes, this is what this does. Please give me an example where this doesn't work. Or... Are you working with some kind of tool where you have a checkbox for case-insensitive, and it is turned on?

Comment: Hello i'm using the regex inside google analytics. As you say ^[A-Z]+\b.* matches a string that starts with an uppercase word, however i need to to match a string starting with at least 4 capitals. Hops that explains it better.